# In scala, why type alias in a class cannot be referred for inheritance?

Tags: scala, inheritance, type-alias

I have the following classes defined:

file: PyRef.scala:

```
package mypackage
class PyBinding() {
...
}

trait PyRef {

  type Binding = PyBinding
}
```

file: Link.scala:

```
class Link() extends PyRef {

  override type Binding = Link.PyBindingImpl
}

object Link {
  class PyBindingImpl() extends PyRef#Binding() {
  }
}
```

In compilation, the following error was thrown:

```
Error:(222, 34) class type required but mypackage.PyBinding found
                 ) extends PyRef#Binding() {
```

Why this happens and what should I do to circumvent it? I'm using Scala 2.10.

Comment: I think you're trying to build something with [typeclasses](https://tpolecat.github.io/2015/04/29/f-bounds.html) and [the aux pattern](https://gigiigig.github.io/posts/2015/09/13/aux-pattern.html).

Comment: Declaring type Binding as covariant or Binding<:PyBinding breaks a few other functions' typecheck, I'm not sure if it worths it.

Comment: @tribboid ... I gave you a bad doc, which made you miss the point. Try this one: http://typelevel.org/cats/typeclasses.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use type projections `A#B` in Scala as instantiatable class types. The following two things work

```
trait Link {
  class PyBindingImpl() extends PyBinding()
}

trait Link {
  val ref: PyRef

  class PyBindingImpl() extends ref.Binding()
}
```